# Minecraft on PC and Wii U

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

If I bought Minecraft Desktop version, can I convert it to Wii U version or maybe just get discount for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.**

Desktop Minecraft and Wii U Minecraft are separate games and you won't get any discount nor free game code for the other platform.

Comment: This also applies to other platforms too, except iDevices and Android devices, but not together (= if you buy it on iPhone, it works on iPad but not Android).